# How to create an SQLlite Database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am writing a simple code to try to see how the database files are created in the data/data/getPackageName()/databases folder. The code is below:

```
package com.package.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
   db .execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR, AGE INT(3));");
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTables VALUES ('Brimelow', 'lee', 37);");
   db.close();  
 }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the above code, I get the following errors below:

```
12-18 10:35:21.568: I/Database(2090): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: MyTables
12-18 10:35:21.568: E/Database(2090): Failure 1 (no such table: MyTables) on 0x125ef0 when preparing 'INSERT INTO MyTables VALUES ('Brimelow', 'lee', 37);'.
12-18 10:35:21.568: W/dalvikvm(2090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d890)
12-18 10:35:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 10:35:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2090): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.test/com.package.test.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MyTables: INSERT INTO MyTables VALUES ('Brimelow', 'lee', 37);
```

Also within Eclipse, I can't seem to find anything in my "data" folder when i search within the file explorer in the DDMS view. I know the database table is failing to create but I don't see where the problem is coming from. Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the table "MyTable" but inserting your values in "MyTables"

Change it to this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('Brimelow', 'lee', 37);");
```

Comment: wow I feel dumb. Thank you Ahmad!

Comment: Hahah no problem. It happens ;)